# BeautifulSoup - Scrape multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the name of the members from each page and move on to the next pages and do the same. My code is working for only one page. I'm very new to this, Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/1")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    lights = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"light"})

    lights_list = []
    for l in lights[0:]:
        result = l.text.strip()
        lights_list.append(result)

    print (lights_list)
```

I tried this and it only gives me the members of the page 3.

```
    for i in range (1,4): #to scrape names of page 1 to 3
    r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/"+ format(i))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
lights = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"light"})

lights_list = []
for l in lights[0:]:
    result = l.text.strip()
    lights_list.append(result)

print (lights_list)
```

Then I tried this :

```
i = 1
while i<5:
    r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/"+str(i))
i+=1

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
lights = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"light"})

lights_list = []
for l in lights[0:]:
    result = l.text.strip()
lights_list.append(result)

print (lights_list)
```

It gives me the name of 4 members, but I don't know from which page

```
['Seng Putheary (Nana)']
['Marco Julia']
['Simon']
['Ms Anne Guerineau']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just two changes needed to be made to get it to scrape everything.

1. `r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/"+ format(i))` needs to be changed to `r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/{}".format(i))`. Your use of format was incorrect.
2. You were not looping over all the code, so the result was that it only printed out one set of names and then had no way to return to the start of the loop. Indenting everything under the for loop fixed that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range (1,4): #to scrape names of page 1 to 3
    r = requests.get("https://www.bodia.com/spa-members/page/{}".format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    lights = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"light"})
    lights_list = []
    for l in lights[0:]:
        result = l.text.strip()
        lights_list.append(result)

    print(lights_list)
```

The above code was spitting out a list of names every 3 seconds for the pages it scraped.

Comment: Is there any way to find out how many pages there are?
On the website i see 1,2,3, but when I click on 3, it changes to 3,4,5.
Is there any way to see how many pages there are, so that i can know range to seyt?

Comment: @taga possibly. That depends on the structure of the website. You could also just scrape until out of pages.